# Message multiple platforms through AWS SNS with aws-ruby-sdk

Tags: android, ios, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-sns

I'm trying to use Amazon's Ruby SDK to send out push notifications with additional attributes for different platforms, namely APNS and GCM (Apple and Android devices), but I cannot find a way to send the documented message structure using the SDK's API.

To send a message with different payloads for GCM and APNS, the docs I found suggest the following structure:

```
{
  "APNS": {
    "aps": {
      "alert": "someone set us up the bomb"
    }
  },
  "GCM": {
    "data": {
      "message": "we get signal"
    }
  }
}
```

I would expect SNS to properly send the platform-specific payload to the correct platform endpoints, but instead the message to, for example, an android device, also includes the APNS payload - it includes the full message body.

Here's how I'm sending the message:

```
sns = AWS::SNS::Client.new
sns.publish(
  target_arn: endpoint_arn,
  message: {
    GCM: ...,
    APNS: ...
  }.to_json
)
```

The available documentation, particularly for the ruby sdk, doesn't seem to be all that detailed. Am I incorrect in my assumption that the payload should be properly distributed depending on the endpoint platform? Is there a better way to achieve what I'm trying to do?

Answer (score 3):

Probably you've already figured this out, but here is how it works on PHP. Probably the message structure is the same is in Ruby:

```
publish(array(
        'TopicArn' => 'YOUR_TOPIC_ARN',
        'Message' => '{ 
                        "default": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "email": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "sqs": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "http": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "https": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "sms": "YOUR_MESSAGE", 
                        "APNS": "{\"aps\":{\"alert\": \"YOUR_MESSAGE\",\"sound\":\"default\", \"badge\":\"1\"} }", 
                        "GCM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"YOUR_MESSAGE\" } }", 
                        "ADM": "{ \"data\": { \"message\": \"YOUR_MESSAGE\" } }"
                    }',
        'MessageStructure' => 'json'
    ));
```

Answer (score 1):

Old story, but here is how I managed to do it, after @user3719626 inspiration:

```
client.publish({
  target_arn: @endpoint_arn,
  message: {
    "default" => "Default message. Used only if the target does not support any other format.",
    "APNS"    => {
                   "aps" => {
                              "alert" => "Whatever!",
                              "url"   => "stackoverflow.com",
                            }
                 }.to_json,
    "GCM"     => {
                   "data" => {
                               "message" => "Whatever!",
                               "url"     => "stackoverflow.com"
                             }
                 }.to_json,
  }.to_json,
  message_structure: 'json',
})
```

Notes:

- `client` is an instance of `AWS::SNS::Client`.
- `@endpoint_arn` is a string containing the target endpoint / topic ARN identifier.
- `message` must be a string, and here it must be a JSON string.
- Each platform key must point to a JSON string as well. So each platform value is "JSONified" twice.

Comment: do you know if we can send some payload (eg: identifier etc) with push that device can use with an action ?

Comment: I do not completely understand your question. If you mean deciding the contents of the payload, yes, you can. There are mainly conditions on the structure (keys in the dictionaries) to respect, and size limits. As a matter of fact, I was already notifying with identifiers in an implementation last year---it is not new.